# enum values in drop down list using ViewData and th viewcode to list it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I create a dropdown list using an enum value in ASP.NET MVC 4?

I have a `Language` enumeration:

```
public enum Language 
{
    English = 0,
    spanish = 2,
    Arabi = 3
}
```

And my property is:

```
public Language Language { get; set; }
```

And my Controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(tList tableSheet)
{         
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

How will I call in my view through a dropdown list using `ViewData[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return

```
Enum.GetNames(typeOf(Language ))


English
spanish
Arabi
```

And this

```
Enum.GetValues(typeOf(Language ))


1,2,3
```

You can languages list to view:

```
ViewBeg.Languages = Enum.GetNames(typeOf(Language)).ToList();
```

Comment: COuld you elaborate it a little more. I mean how to pass it using viewdata and get it in html?

Comment: Could you please hlp m with the view code... Is it like??<@Html.DropDownList("Languages", (SelectList) ViewBag.Languages)

Comment: You could use this in your template: `Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.EnumProperty, Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumtype)).Cast<enumtype>().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() }))`

Comment: is there a typo on the last line `ViewBeg` instead of `ViewBag`?

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm late to the party but... check out a helper class I created to do just this...

http://jnye.co/Posts/4/creating-a-dropdown-list-from-an-enum-in-mvc-and-c%23

This helpe can be used as follows:

**In the controller:**

```
//If you don't have an enum value use the type
ViewBag.DropDownList = EnumHelper.SelectListFor<Language>();

//If you do have an enum value use the value (the value will be marked as selected)
ViewBag.DropDownList = EnumHelper.SelectListFor(myEnumValue);
```

**In the view**

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropDownList")
```

**Helper:**

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    //Creates a SelectList for a nullable enum value
    public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>(T? selected)
        where T : struct
    {
        return selected == null ? SelectListFor<T>()
                                : SelectListFor(selected.Value);
    }

    //Creates a SelectList for an enum type
    public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>() where T : struct
    {
        Type t = typeof (T);
        if (t.IsEnum)
        {
            var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<enum>()
                             .Select(e => new { Id = Convert.ToInt32(e), Name = e.GetDescription() });

            return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name");
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Creates a SelectList for an enum value
    public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>(T selected) where T : struct 
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        if (t.IsEnum)
        {
            var values = Enum.GetValues(t).Cast<Enum>()
                             .Select(e => new { Id = Convert.ToInt32(e), Name = e.GetDescription() });

            return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", Convert.ToInt32(selected));
        }
        return null;
    } 

    // Get the value of the description attribute if the 
    // enum has one, otherwise use the value.
    public static string GetDescription<TEnum>(this TEnum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        if (fi != null)
        {
            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
             (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
    typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
    false);

            if (attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                 return attributes[0].Description;
            }
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The link given by you doesn't open for me.

Comment: Hmm? I just tried it myself and seemed to work fine... what do you get? a 404?

Comment: I got "Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.ninjanye.co.uk". I'm from Ukraine, could it be a reason?

Comment: Odd... what happens if you manually type in `www.ninjanye.co.uk`...?

Comment: The same, maybe dns resolver not working somehow... can you give me ip for your site?

Comment: In chrome go to `Settings > Show advanced settings` and uncheck the options around predicting network actions (top 3 links) http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/U_58CisMRAQ

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I got the error: Error 105 (net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED): Unable to resolve the server's DNS address. I doubt that it's related with browser settings because I tried it with Firefox and IE and getting the same result. Maybe I can check with IP of your site?

Comment: It's ok.  I'll investigate my end. Thanks

Comment: I hope that it will be fixed soon.

Comment: Yeah, the important content from the blog is all here in the post so you are not missing out on anything